# JavaFX detecting mouse over edge of pane

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm implementing some pane drag-resizing in JavaFX, but I can't find any info about correct approach for detecting mouse-over edge of element. I can simply calculate it from mouse position and size of element, but I don't want to reinvent a wheel if there is already dedicated method.

Comment: There is nothing built-in that provides this.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was searching for some libraries with such components, but didn't find any, so I guess I'll have to make my own solution.

Comment: I am new to Java/JavaFX myself and this may be completely wrong, but could you possibly achieve this by wrapping the pane in another pane and setting an `onMouseHover` event on the parent pane? I have never attempted this myself, but that is my first thought of something to try.